# I have a vb program,but it gave me the wrong result?

Tags: vba, vb6

```
Dim n As Integer = 1, year As Integer

    Do Until 6000000000 / (2 * n) = 6000000
        year = 2008 - 40 * n
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    txtResult.Text = "The world population would have been less than 6 million in the year " & year
```

As the code that I showed above, I tried to make my program to determine in which year the population from 6 billion in 2008 reduced to or less than 6 million.(Assume the population is doubled every 40 years). However, when I run the program, it won't show result which is the year 1608.
It would be so helpful is anyone could help me to correct my code! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume this is a homework question? Re-read the parts of your textbook dealing with floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA you will have the following code working as expected:

```
Sub qtest()
Dim n As Integer, year As Integer
Dim Population As Double
    n = 1
    year = 2008
    Population = 6000000000#

    Do Until Population <= 6000000
        Population = Population / 2
        year = year - 40
        n = n + 1      'you don't need it but I left it here
    Loop

MsgBox "The world population would have been less than 6 million in the year " & year

End Sub
```